# High resolution monitor (2560x1440) to NVIDIA 9700M with HDMI

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, external-display, laptop-display

I have an Acer Aspire-8930G laptop and I want to connect it to my 27" screen. The graphic card is NVIDIA 9700M, which supposedly supports up to two screens with 2560x1440 resolution.

The laptop has a HDMI out and the monitor needs a DVI-D (Dual Link). I have a Dual Link Cable and an adapter.

But the maximum resolution that it lets me choose is 1280x800 pixels! If I choose in the advance settings to show all possible resolutions I can also choose 1920x1080 32 bit, but it is also not what I want.

What do I have to do to choose the native resolution 2560x1440?

Comment: how can i find out that? the cable is the original and the adapter has all pins used: http://sound-affair.com/image/data/Cables_and_Parts/avocent-dvi-hdmi-adapter-lg.jpg

Comment: Crap. I will delete the comment. My mind was on DisplayPort to DVI conversion. HDMI to DVI should be simple since HDMI basically is DVI+sound. I do not see why it would not 'just work' (though obviously it does not, else you woult not be posting here).

Comment: HDMI can not be converted to dual link DVI.

Comment: Displayport to DVI-D conversion is possible with an active converter/cable. Most include a USB cable for power.

Comment: Did you connect the monitor in extend mode (Windows+P)? In mirror mode the common resolution is the lower of the two screens because of course you cannot display that resolution on your laptop unless it's really that high